# PostgreSQL execute statement on same user - but with different privilidges

Tags: postgresql

I need to run multiple user-defined SQL scripts - some using schema modification privileges, others only data modification privileges.

I can do this by executing them using different users (with adequate privileges), however I need to execute all scripts in single transaction.

Is there a way to specify privileges for single SQL statement on existing connection?

Thank you!

Comment: `set role`? or `set authorization`?

Comment: An alternative is a `SECURITY DEFINER` function.